# Newtonsoft could not be found - Building a project using MSBuild tools 2017

Tags: .net-framework, c#, build

I'm trying to build a project using MSBuild tools 2017 since I don't have a VS installed in my PC. The problem is that there's an error whenever I try to build it, which is:

*"The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

I tried to install Newtonsoft.json using this command `NuGet.exe install "PROJECTNAME/packages.config" -o packages/`but it shows:

*"'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'."*

I'm stuck on this trying to get this build to work. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. I just added Newtonsoft.json.dll to my project and referenced it in my .csproj file.